# Pistachios - Taste and Sound Great

Tags: foley

I recently finished a film which required foley for cannibal natives.

I needed foley for shell and bone necklaces.

I had nowhere to turn to,

until a friend of mine discarded his pistachio shell cup!

I was saved!

I bought a bag of roasted and salted pistachios.

Taking a handful, I began to create some very convincing foley for the natives running about.

I'll upload some samples tomorrow with an update to this post.

Comment: I bet you could get some neat rain sounds out of 'em too.  Betcha could get a nice neck break out of mashing them with a rubber mallot.  

Comment: @g.a.harry Shh. That was going to be the next Onomonopeya Sharades!

Comment: Dammit. Me and my big mouth...

Comment: @Utopia: hi there! I was searching here for similar effects. Do you still have some samples you could share for those recordings? Thank you!

Comment: @Melissa Absolutely. Shoot me your e-mail and I'll send you off a couple.

Answer (score 2):

interesting... did you make a chain out of them or just held them in your hand?

Comment: Moved them between hands and hopped up and down with them in one of those small mesh bags you get those chocolate coins in.

Answer (score 1):

After reading this I feel a hundred times less-strange than before, as I've just accumulated a full glass of pistachio shells over the past few days. Decided to save them for some experimentation :D

Comment: Nice! I also recorded them when they were still in-tact (i.e. not eaten). Sounded good both ways, but there is more low-end when it's still in tact.

Answer (score 1):

oh yeah, pistacios always sounded great to me..taste great too, hard to get enough.  such amazing shells.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is making me crave some pistachios.

That is all.

Answer (score 1):

Pistachios, is there anything they cant do?